# Which video-format is the most compact while still compatible for playback on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video

Right now my choice is quicktime .mov with H.264 at 30% quality.

I have a small demo video which I want to include, and file-size has the highest priority. I know H.264 is the best choice because it is hardware accelerated. But maybe there is a video format which gives about the same quality with smaller file size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H.264 will be your format of choice. To save further bits you can use a better encoder, as QuickTime is quite inefficient. The most efficient H.264 encoders are all based on [x264](http://x264.nl).

A nice x264 based open-source option with a GUI and device presets is [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: As far as I know After Effects uses QuickTime to compress H.264. You could try to use a x264 based [QuickTime plugin](http://dcs.co.at/ftp) instead, though you have to be careful about selecting the right compression options since not all are supported on ios.

Comment: You need to use x264 to get the smallest encoded h.264 videos. It produces the smallest and best looking videos. The Apple encoder is nowhere near as good at low bit rates.

Answer (score 0):

a standard mp4 is probably the most compact video out there